# relative font-size of <sub> or <sup> and their descendants in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, font-size, sup

Trying the "[Eric Meyer Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/)" I stumbled across an issue concerning the `font-size:100%` declaration to reset the font size of all suitable elements. `font-size:100%` means the elements should inherit `font-size` property of their parent, but this is not the case with the  `<sub>` and `<sup>` elements and their descendants in IE (tested in 6,7,8 and 9th version).

For example (or [this live example on a playground](http://jsfiddle.net/PGQ48/)):

```
// CSS:
sup,span {font-size:100%;}
// HTML:
if you try this in IE, <sup>this text will be smaller <span>and this even more</span></sup>
```

It seems like just another implementation trick, that IE plays on webdesigners, [since this is not the only glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887666/ie-ignores-font-size-for-html-sub-elements) of these elements. My guess is that IE applies some own hard-wired styling on the `<sub>` and `<sup>` elements which makes their content smaller in addition to being sub-/superscripted, but I can't find a way to reset this behaviour, if any exists at all.

*// Please respond directly to this issue, suggestions like "use an UA specific stylesheet" may satisfy your feeling of being helpful, but doesn't satisfy the topic :-) ..EDIT: Ok, this plea has finally turned against me, but I wanted to state at least one answer to this topic here.*

**EDIT:** It looks like IE (all versions till IE9) multiplies the font size of the `<sub>` and `<sup>` and their descendants with some variable coefficient (sth between **0.6 – 0.8** depending on the font-size).

*The reasoning is following*: when a fixed size (e.g. `font-size:15px`) is set on the `<sup>` tag and all its descendants, they all have the font size around 10px (≅ **0.7** × 15px). But, when a relative size is being set instead (e.g. `font-size:100%`), the coefficient effect is propagated from the `<sup>` element down to its descendants – so 1st-level descendant has the font size around 70% (≅ **0.7** × 100% of its `<sup>` parent), 2nd-level descendant has the font size around 50% (≅ **0.7** × **0.7** × 100% of its `<sup>` ancestor) and so on. This propagation breaks when `font-size:inherit` is used, since it means the element should have exactly the same size as its parent – this works for the descendants of the `<sup>` element, but the `<sup>` element itself is still given a smaller font size by IE than its parent element does have.

The coefficient theory :-) taking part in IE can be seen on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/PGQ48/7/). Also compare this with any of the "standard compliant" browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the only "solution" to leave the `font-size:100%` reset-declaration in the stylesheet  and still have acceptable sub-/superscripts is so far either to:

- Use a different element for styling the sub-/superscripts, e.g. `<span>`. Definitely not a good idea in the light of semantics → *eliminated*.
- Use an UserAgent-specific stylesheet, conditional comments at best (which is what I was worried about, because i didn't have to use them for IE ≥ 7, until now) and explictly restyle each descendant to compensate the "coefficient effect" → *it's not worth it :-)*.
- Leave it as it is so everybody can see IE has its own rules (ideally/naively this could force them to fix it in the next version) and use `font-size:inherit` to have at least the descendants of `<sub>` or `<sup>` be the same size by default in IE ≥ 8 → *accepted*.

---

**solution #2**, this will do the trick (sure it can be tuned up, but just the concept):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
  sup *,sub * {font-size:120%; font-size:inherit;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

provided you don't strive for maximum performance (See the [`*` selector performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071203/why-not-reset-css-using-the-asterisk)).

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me, I had to add `!important` to the font-size for IE6-7 and then it did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but it works so far:

```
sup,
sub {
    font-size: inherit;   /* all browser */
    font-size: 120%\0/;   /* wie only */
}
```